# Using a loop to populate unbound Textbox on a report for all records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I recently came across a document which numbers all record lines from 1 to the end of the document. I then thought the document can be created in our database in form of a `report`. The numbering has been used in the document for years for easy visualisation and reference.

How do I add this numbering onto the `report`? I have attempted to use a `loop` but then I get a repeat of numbering associated with the last record only.

```
Private Sub Report_Activate()
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Total = 0
For Counter = 1 To 10
Total = Counter + 1

Me.txtLine.Value = Counter
'Debug.Print Counter

Next Counter

End Sub
```

Current Attempt:

[image]

Expected: NB Sorting on `Description` is not important

[image]

Comment: Oh my days. Had no idea about `RunningSum` property works great. And thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use textbox RunningSum property. It is only available on report, not form. No VBA needed. Set ControlSource to: `=1`. Then RunningSum property to OverAll or OverGroup.

Calculating sequential identifier or any running sum in query or with code gets rather complicated in Access. It is a common topic in many forums.